# Debian : Mounting a raid array

Tags: debian, mount, partition, raid, disk

I have a Debian system on which we migrated to a SSD for faster execution. Before that we had a 2.0Tb hard disks in RAID. Now we want to use the RAID drives to perform storage generated by the application.

I tried using the mount command to mount one of the disks, but it failed.

fdisk -l output :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00089ca4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    33556480    16777216+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2        33558528    34607104      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3        34609152  3907027120  1936208984+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 58369 cylinders, total 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00047ef7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    33556480    16777216+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc2        33558528    34607104      524288+  83  Linux
/dev/sdc3        34609152   937701040   451545944+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000275d2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    33556480    16777216+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2        33558528    34607104      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3        34609152  3907027120  1936208984+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

As you can see there are two 2Tb hard disks in RAID. Is there any way I can format them to one single partition on both drives and mount them to lets say /media/attachment?? Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: You can merge the two disks and create one usable partition. Do you want one 2TB partition as RAID 1 (mirrored across the two disks) or one 4TB partition as RAID 0 (sharing the disks)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there are two 2Tb hard disks in RAID. Is there any way I can format them to one single partition on both drives and mount them to lets say /media/attachment

*For the purposes of this answer I am using `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. It is your responsibility to ensure that this matches your situation.*

You can do this provided you are happy to erase all the data on these two disks.

1. Ensure the disks are unused and you have taken a backup of any data on them that you wanted to keep
2. Using `fdisk` or your preferred alternative, erase the partition table and create a single partition covering the entire disk. This will leave you with partitions `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`
3. EITHER

   - Create a RAID 1 device, which we will identify as `/dev/md1`, using these two physical partitions

     ```
     mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=raid1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
     ```

   OR

   - Create a RAID 0 device, also identified as `/dev/md1`

     ```
     mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=raid0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
     ```
4. Save the metadata for boot time

   ```
   mdadm --examine --brief /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
   ```
5. Create the filesystem. Notice that the RAID device is `/dev/md1` and from this point on you rarely need to reference `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb1`

   ```
   mkfs -t ext4 -L bigdisk /dev/md1
   ```
6. Mount it. Don't forget to update `/etc/fstab` if you want this configured permanently

   ```
   mkdir -p /media/attachment
   mount /dev/md1 /media/attachment
   ```

You can `cat /proc/mdstat` to see the state of the RAID device. If you are running as RAID 1 this will show you the synchronisation status.

Comment: I will check this out in sometime as soon as I take a backup and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have 2 separate disks or still in RAID1? For the first one use `mdadm` to remove the disks from the raid configuration and the you can use `fdisk` to create a partition on each of them. With LVM you then can combine them to 1 disk of 4TB.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: I am not an expert in this matter. I only know that this tool exists for this purpose. Run `mdamd --help` and it will give you the help info. In there there is: `mdadm --incremental device` to add/remove a device to/from an array as appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, i cannot mess around as this is production server I am dealing with.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot help you with exact commands. Just tried to give you an approach.  Do you have a testing machine on which you can create a RAID and then 'remove' it?

Comment: One safe way to test is to use a loop device. `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 of=/tmp/a ; losetup -v /dev/loop1 /tmp/a` and repeat for `/tmp/b` and `/dev/loop2`. Then you can `fdisk`, `mdadm`, `mkfs`, and even `mount` with those two `loopN` devices and the consequent `mdN` RAID device